# Representing volatile variable in UML diagram

Tags: java, uml

```
private volatile boolean serviceHealthy;
```

private boolean is easy enough, since it's just

```
- serviceHealthy : boolean
```

However I have not been able to find how to appropriately represent a volatile variable in UML. Is that indicative of the answer, that you don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expanding on Thomas Kilian's answer a bit.

Neither the UML metamodel nor the standard UML profile, support modeling the semantics of the Volatile keyword. Creating your own custom stereotype `<<volatile>>` is a nice lightweight approach to expressing your intentions.

Stereotypes are technically required to exist inside a profile, so to first you just need to create a profile in your modeling tool. This can be done inside your current model or externally and then imported. If you want to use it on multiple models, you should define the profile in its own model.

Once the profile is created just create a new stereotype and give it the name `volatile`. This stereotype should extend the `Property` metaclass; property is essentially just UML's term for attributes.

Now you just apply that stereotype to your volatile attributes.

Let me know if you have any follow-up questions. It may seem complicated but once you do it once, its actually quite easy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can just stereotype it with `<<volatile>>`.